# Selecting rows where consecutive values change while ignoring NAs

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I want to find rows where value changes within a vector that contains `NA`s. For example, I have a following vector

```
x = c(1, 2, 6, 3, 3, 9, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4)
```

I can use this code `which(x[-1] != x[-length(x)]) + 1` and it will give me row numbers when values where changed: **2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10**.

If I replace `x[x>4] <- NA` and rerun the same code, the output will be the row **2** only. But I want to consider all `NA`s as changes *except* if the previous value is also `NA`and deal with the value after as change.

My desired output for `x = c(1, 2, NA, 3, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA, 4, 4)` would be output of following row numbers: **2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10**

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Do you want to (a) omit NAs from the input vector and then look for changes? (b) Consider all NAs as changes? (c) Consider all NAs as changes *except* if the previous value is also NA? (d) Something else? And how do you want to deal with the value after an NA - is that a change?

Comment: A good test case would be `x = c(1, 2, NA, 3, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA, 4, 4)`. What is your desired output for that?

Comment: I want to consider NAs as a unique value. In other words, consider all NAs as changes except if the previous value is also NA and deal with the value after as change.

Comment: My desired output for `x = c(1, 2, NA, 3, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA, 4, 4)` would be output of following row numbers: 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to change `NA` with other conventional representation of missing values, such as -9999. After this you can use your method `which(x[-1] != x[-length(x)]) + 1`, or try `rle` function from base R.

```
# Sample data
x = c(1, 2, NA, 3, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA, 4, 4)

# Replace missing values with -9999
x[is.na(x)] <- -9999

# Calculate position of non-equal consecutive values
cumsum(rle(x)$length) + 1

# NOTE: you will need to remove last element of the output
```